# Gradient effect not showing in layout android

Tags: android, gradient, android-drawable

Hi I am working with gradient effects in my android app.

In the layout I have used 2 drawable layouts to put the background for some views to apply gradient effects.

The layout is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/music_individual_album_top_gradient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/music_individual_album_top_gradient_height"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/album_option_gradient_top"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewIdAlbumCover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/music_individual_album_option_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/album_option_gradient_bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addqueueAlbum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/music_individual_album_top_gradient_height"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/album_button_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:text="+Queue"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareAlbum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addqueueAlbum"
            android:background="@drawable/album_button_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:text="Share"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favouriteAlbum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shareAlbum"
            android:background="@drawable/album_button_shape"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/favourite_heart"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:text="122"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moreAlbum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/more"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/album_play_queue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/albums_play" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

In that layout I have used the following xml files for background which contains the gradient effects.

1. album_option_gradient_bottom.xml
2. album_option_gradient_top.xml

The view @+id/music_individual_album_top_gradient has the gradient effect from album_option_gradient_top.xml. But while executing , its not reflecting the gradient effect.

**1. album_option_gradient_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#05ffffff"
    android:startColor="#F2000000"
    android:useLevel="true" />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />
```

**2. album_option_gradient_top.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#05ffffff"
    android:endColor="#F2000000"
    android:useLevel="true" />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />
```

I am expecting the effect as the image has.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not posting whole layout, just the image with two drawable for your reference to include in your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/album_option_gradient_top"/>

    <View
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/album_option_gradient_bottom"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```